# Call sensor activity object from another class

Tags: java, android

I am working on a project in which the content on the screen changes with the direction of mobile's axis. For this, I created a class which calculates azimuthal angle by accessing sensor data. This class also has a method `setLine` which gives back a,b,c in line equation `a.x + b.y + c = 0` when supplied gps co-ordinates. This line is the z-axis of mobile.

So I created an object of this class from another class. But whenever I am accessing `setLine`, By seeing the log I got to know that `azimuthal = NULL` and `oldAzimuthal = Math.PI/180` which is what I set.

I don't understand this. When I created the `ViewAngleActivity` object, this should have already initialized sensors and I shouldn't be getting `NULL` for `azimuthal` .

Earlier when I used This`ViewAngleActivity` as the main class I didn't face such issue. I was properly getting `azimthal`.

Am I missing some concepts? Please help.

I am uploading the code for `ViewAngleActivity`

```
public class ViewAngleActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {


    Float azimuth;  
    Float pitch;
    Float roll;

    float oldAzimuth;

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    Sensor accelerometer;
    Sensor magnetometer;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        magnetometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
        Log.d("gettingViewAngle:","in onCreateSensor got Created");
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {  }

    float[] mGravity;
    float[] mGeomagnetic;

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
            mGravity = event.values;

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
            mGeomagnetic = event.values;

        if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
            float R[] = new float[9];
            float I[] = new float[9];

            if (SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic)) {

                // orientation contains azimut, pitch and roll
                float orientation[] = new float[3];
                SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);

                oldAzimuth = azimuth;
                azimuth = orientation[0];
                pitch = orientation[1];
                roll = orientation[2];

                // at this point, orientation contains the azimuth(direction), pitch and roll values.

                Log.d("onSensorChanged:", "azimuth = "+ azimuth);
                Log.d("onSensorChanged:", "oldAzimuth = "+ oldAzimuth);
            }

        }
    }

    /**
     * This method calculates line equation of mobile axis
     * @param currentLatitude
     * @param currentLongitude
     * @return co-efficients of the line a.x + b.y + c = 0
     */
    public double[] setLine(Double currentLatitude, Double currentLongitude){

        double angle = 1;
        double a,b,c;
        double[] coEfficients = {1, 1, 0};
        Log.d("setLine:", "azimuth = "+ azimuth);
        Log.d("setLine:", "oldAzimuth = "+ oldAzimuth);

        if(azimuth!= null) {
            angle = (float) azimuth;
            if (angle == 0){
                angle = Math.PI/180;
            }
            if ( angle%((Math.PI)/2) ==0){
                a = 0;
                b = 1;
                c = ( - currentLongitude);
            }
            else {
                a = -(Math.tan((double) angle));
                b = 1;
                c = (Math.tan((double) angle) * currentLatitude) - currentLongitude;
            }
            Log.d("setLine:Using azimuth", "azimuth = "+ angle);

            coEfficients[0] = a ;
            coEfficients[1] = b ;
            coEfficients[2] = c ;

        }
        else{
            angle = (float) oldAzimuth;
            if (angle == 0){
                angle = Math.PI/180;
            }

            if ( angle%((Math.PI)/2) ==0){
                a = 0;
                b = 1;
                c = ( - currentLongitude);
            }
            else {
                a = -(Math.tan((double) angle));
                b = 1;
                c = (Math.tan((double) angle) * currentLatitude) - currentLongitude;
            }
            Log.d("setLine:UsingOldAzimuth", "oldAzimuth = "+ angle);

            coEfficients[0] = a ;
            coEfficients[1] = b ;
            coEfficients[2] = c ;
        }



        return coEfficients;
    }

}
```

The object I created from other class is as follows

```
private ViewAngleActivity viewAngleActivity;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  viewAngleActivity = new ViewAngleActivity();

  //other parts of the code//

  }

@Override
public void method1{
  method2;
  }

public void method1{
  double[] coEfficients = viewAngleActivity.setLine(currentLatitude,currentLongitude);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You're only creating an instance of **ViewAngleActivity**, it's never really added to the window.
- Your `onCreate()` and `onResume()` methods never get called, they are only called when your Activity is added to the window and goes through the [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)
- Since you're instantiating your **mSensorManager** instance inside `onCreate()`, it never gets created and is still null.
- Since `onResume()` isn't called (see second point up there), then your **viewAngleActivity** instance (which is also your SensorEventListener interface) never gets registered to **mSensorManager**, and as such the method `onSensorChanged(SensorEvent evt)` inside your ViewAngleActivity instance never gets called. Since that's where you're setting azimuth it's still going to be NULL cause that method is never called.

You might want to try a different approach, probably move all the code in your ViewAngleActivity's `onCreateView()` methods to a constructor like so:

```
//note the context parameter, pass this one when you create your ViewAngleActivity instance
public ViewAngleActivity(Context context){
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        magnetometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
        Log.d("gettingViewAngle:","in onCreateSensor got Created");
        //then you use your context to reg.
        mSensorManager.registerListener(context, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(context, magnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }
```

Please read more about Android's [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and how they are added on screen. Note that with the above approach, you'd have to handle unregistering your **SensorEventListener**, cause obviously `onPause()` would never be called in **ViewAngleActivity**.

```
//this is how you'd probably go about it:
viewAngleActivty.mSensorManager.unregisterListener(viewAngleActivity);
```

Or instead, implement what you're trying to do in the new Activity you're using as your MainActivity, that would be even easier.

Comment: Thanks Joey for the suggestion. I shifted the entire code to MainActivity and it is working fine.